# can't install gems (Using rvm) no permission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I just installed rvm and after that i installed ruby1.9.2.
i have a problem with installing gems.

I get the following error when doing:
gem install capistrano
no such file to load -- rubygems

This is how i set it up (its ubuntu):
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
gem -v
no such file to load -- rubygems

somebody any idea how to fix this ?

--- EDIT---- 
ok so i tried to fix it by uninstalling ruby and installing it again. 
But no luck! :( 
rvm remove 1.9.2 ; rvm install 1.9.2

doesn't work..

Comment: Are you sure you're using the gem command that rvm installed?  What does `which gem` say?

Answer (score 2):

I think that when this happens, it means rubygems did not get installed for the current version, or it can't be found. In the latter case, it's the PATH issue mentioned in other answers here. If rubygems did NOT get installed however, try this:

```
  $ rvm rubygems current
```

rvm will download and install the latest rubygems for your setup. You will likely need to reinstall any gems for this rvm profile at this point.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so to solve this problem i did the following.
Login to my ec2 management console.. selected the image and deleted it!

Then started new ubuntu image. 
run some commands.. and voila problem solved.

For people who have the same problem. I am sorry but i don't have the answer. I just gave up (after hours of searching and trying etc. etc. ).